# Dart / Flutter confusion with 'Use generic function type syntax for parameters' (use_function_type_syntax_for_parameters)

Tags: function, flutter, dart, generics, parameters

I'm getting this warning in vscode, and  I'm unsure how to resolve it. The 'Use generic function type syntax for parameters' warning is shown in vscode below.:

[image]

However, I've been unable to understand the dart-lang.github to understand what I'm doing wrong:
https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/use_function_type_syntax_for_parameters.html

What is particularly odd is the number of blue-underlined parameters in vscode (shown in the picture) I'm still not sure if it is complaining about the Sort() function, or the getField() function.  (I think it's the former?)

What is the correct way to write that function to satisfy that recommendation?

Here's the code:

```
@override
  void sort<T>(Comparable<T> getField(Question d), bool ascending) {  <-- warning on this line
    data.sort(( a,  b) {
      if (!ascending) {
        final Question c = a;
        a = b;
        b = c;
      }
      final Comparable<T> aValue = getField(a);
      final Comparable<T> bValue = getField(b);
      return Comparable.compare(aValue, bValue);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Comparable<T> getField(Question d)` to `Comparable<T> Function(Question d) getField` as your link recommends.